# Rotating wave approximation and linear response function

Tags: quantum-optics, absorption, linear-systems

Is it true that the rotating wave approximation (RWA) is only the thing for the non-linear cases, and in the linear regime it does give any benefits? Let us say we have a rotating wave, so we don't need to make any approximation:

$$E(t) = e^{i\omega t}$$

Using it, we find the linear response function $\chi(\omega)$ without RWA. Note, that the frequency domain is not restricted only by positive frequencies here. Now we consider the plane signal being a linear combination:

$$E(t) = e^{i\omega t} + e^{-i\omega t}$$

Since the system is linear, the response is simply:

$$P(\omega) = \chi(\omega) e^{i\omega t} + \chi(-\omega) e^{-i\omega t}$$.

Please confirm or correct me.

Comment: > *"Let us say we have a rotating wave, so we don't need to make any approximation:"* Why do you call $e^{i\omega t}$ a "rotating wave"? It seems more like a phasor for harmonically oscillating electric field. And why do you think we don't need to make any approximation? RWA is, in general, omission of certain fast frequency terms in equations describing the system, so they are easier to solve. What kind of system do you think of and what are the equations describing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rotating frame approximation is only relevant went there is some additional dynamics of interest. Examples of such additional dynamics include nonlinearities. The pure linear evolution represented by $\exp(i\omega t)$ is then removed by considering the system as if it is "rotating" at the rate represented by $\omega$. Without such additional dynamics, there would not be much point in using the rotating frame approximation.

Note that a plane wave is not just the time dependent factor, but would include also a spatial dependence. Moreover, plane waves don't need to be real valued functions. So the general expression for a plane wave is $\exp(i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})$. When you add the complex conjugate, the result is a real valued function, which is often used to represent an electric field. However, it is quite common to use the complex exponential form with only the positive (or negative) frequencies, knowing that the physical electric field can be recovered by extracted the real part.